# Int32.CompareTo(int x) performance

Tags: c#, performance, boxing

Does the following have any performance issues (e.g. performing boxing)?

```
public int CompareIntValues(int left, int right)
{
    return left.CompareTo(right);
}
```

Some further information. The application is supposed to be soft real time, so using C# is perhaps an odd choice. However, that's out of my hands.

Comment: Are you actually having performance issues with this code? If not, you are micro-optimizing.

Comment: I'm not sure, since CompareTo implements IComparable, but it shouldn't be an issue
unless CompareIntValues is called many, many times within a single second.

Comment: Agree with Oded, if you are concerned about performance in this context, you should probably be using a lower level language.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't profiled the code yet. However, this is called a large number of times in performance critical code.

Comment: @Jack: Unfortunately that's not my decision, but your point is taken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There wouldn't be any boxing with what you have as Int32 defines two overloads to [CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.compareto.aspx), one that takes an `int` and one that takes an `object`. In your example above, the former will be called. If the latter must be called, then boxing would occur.

Comment: Apologies for the naive follow up question, but `left` isn't boxed is it?

Comment: @Rob - No, it would not be boxed either.

Answer (score 13):

It's time for everyone's favourite game show: BOX OR NO BOX!

```
public string DoIntToString(int anInt)
{
    return anInt.ToString();
}
```

**BOX** or **NO BOX**? Let's go to the IL:

```
IL_0001: ldarga.s anInt
IL_0003: call instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
```

**NO BOX**. `ToString()` is a `virtual` method on `object` that is overridden by `int`. Since `struct`s can't participate in non-interface inheritence, the compiler knows that there are no subclasses of `int`, and can generate a call to the `int` version of `ToString()` directly.

---

```
static Type DoIntGetType(int anInt)
{
    return anInt.GetType();
}
```

**BOX** or **NO BOX**? Let's go to the IL:

```
IL_0001: ldarg.0
IL_0002: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0007: call instance class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Object::GetType()
```

**BOX**. `GetType()` is *not* `virtual` on `object`, so there is no `int` version of the method. The argument has to be boxed, and the call is made on the new boxed object.

---

```
private static string DoIntToStringIFormattable(int anInt)
{
    return anInt.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

**BOX** or **NO BOX**? Let's go to the IL:

```
IL_0001: ldarga.s anInt
IL_0003: call class [mscorlib]System.Globalization.CultureInfo [mscorlib]System.Globalization.CultureInfo::get_CurrentCulture()
IL_0008: call instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString(class [mscorlib]System.IFormatProvider)
```

**NO BOX**. Even though `ToString(IFormattable)` is an implementation of the `IFormatProvider` interface, the call itself is being made directly against the `int`. For the same reason as the first method, no box is required.

---

So for the final round, we have your method:

```
public int CompareIntValues(int left, int right)
{
    return left.CompareTo(right);
}
```

Knowing that `CompareTo(int)` is implicit implementation of `IComparable<int>`, you make the call: **BOX** or **NO BOX**?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why structure types could not implement GetType() as a static function (one definition per structure type) which simply returned the appropriate instance of Type?  By my understanding, even something like "return New KeyValuePair<T,U>.GetType()", run within a routine that was generic on T and U, would be a constant, since every different combination of T and U would result in a separate version of that routine being JITted.

Comment: So does it boxing?